# Is it possible to combine 2 background colors in css?

Tags: html, css

I have an element with gradient as background color,

```css
.foo{
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #7cd4cf, #7cd4cf 1.5px, #49c8c1 2px, #49c8c1 4px);
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">

</div>
```

I need to add an overlay of gradient on the top of it - so it will looks like this :
[image: Pic]

As you can see - it's got gradient from left to right - on the top of the stripes.

I've tried add it by using :after - and it's working - but i already have pseudo element for this element - so it's override it. Is it possible to add more then one :after element? or perhaps their is a better way achieving that effect with only Css ? (no js please).

Thanks

Comment: Check this, maybe it helps you: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's possible, if and *only* if the overlay is going to be a solid color. You simply overlay an additional horizontal gradient over the underlying repeating linear gradient, with `#7cd4cf` fading out to opacity of 0.

- Top layer: a linear gradient starting with `#7cd4cf` at opacity 1 from left, ending with opacity 0 on the right
- Bottom layer: your original pattern

With that logic in mind, the top layer can be coded like this: `linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(124,212,207, 1), rgba(124,212,207,0))`. Note that the corresponding rgb colors of `#7cd4cf` is `rgb(124,212,207)`.

Note that background-images stack from bottom to top, i.e. the last specified background image will be at the bottom of the stack.

```css
.foo {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(124, 212, 207, 1), rgba(124, 212, 207, 0)),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #7cd4cf, #7cd4cf 1.5px, #49c8c1 2px, #49c8c1 4px);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap `linear-gradient` of the perticular `div`. Like this

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, pink 50%, cyan 50%);
```

In your code

```
.foo{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, cyan 50%);
}
```

If you want further details check this link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v14m59pq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

2 gradients with transparency:

```css
.foo{
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #7cd4cf, #7cd4cf 1.5px, rgba(73, 200, 193, 0.3) 2px, rgba(73, 200, 193, 0.3) 4px), linear-gradient(45deg, #7cd4cf, rgba(73, 200, 193, 0.3));
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">

</div>
```